# I have hosted an ASP.NET web service with Entity Framework on IIS, how to access it using ip?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, iis

I have hosted an ASP.NET web service on IIS. But I am not able to access it using ip.

For example: if I type my device ip into the browser on the same device, I am not able to access it. And in IIS also, when I use `localhost` as hostname, the web service is accessible but I am not able to access the database.

I have attached screenshot which shows error message when accessing one of the method in web service which access database.

Here is my `web.config`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GhC2a.png)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" 
                 type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false" />
    </configSections>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.1" />
        <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.6.1" />
    </system.web>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <serviceBehaviors>
                <behavior>
                    <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
                    <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
                </behavior>
            </serviceBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <protocolMapping>
            <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
        </protocolMapping>
        <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
    </system.serviceModel>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
        <directoryBrowse enabled="true" />
    </system.webServer>
    <entityFramework>
        <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
        <providers>
            <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
        </providers>
    </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Chromoscan2Entities"  
             connectionString="metadata=res://*/CytoModel.csdl|res://*/CytoModel.ssdl|res://*/CytoModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=WIN10D-02198;initial catalog=Chromoscan2;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
             providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

Comment: Check if you find anything like ';server'; on your files

Comment: and code of that method that's throwing the error? BTW, easiest thing to do would be to put a breakpoint into method and step through it in debugger

Comment: Beginners can easily neglect the fact that it is IIS site bindings that control what URL you can use in browsers, https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/binding-diagnostics.html Run the report and learn the details. If the site bindings do not accept URL with IP addresses, either you use the proper URL instead, or you edit the binding accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can publish your website to the "Default Web Site" found on IIS.

If its not there you can do the following:

1. Change the website's name to "`Default Web Site`"
2. Set the app pool to default one
3. Make sure the site's path is at `inetpub\wwwroot`

Comment: i have done that.my hosted files are on this path only.it works only if while creating site in iis, i keep host name as localhost,if i keep some other name it wont browse.and in local host also i am unable to access database.